# I have a dataset containing a date column and a moment(Force* Distance) column. How do I perform a time integration in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, math, jupyter-notebook

The lower limit should be Day 1 (my first data) and the upper limit for the integration should be the most recent date in the dataset.

I could imagine a time-integration such as ∫ M(t) dt

[Nm·hr] or [Nm·day].

Example of dataset

| local_dttm | Moment (Nm) |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-07-14 10:50:00 | 6245.16 |
| 2021-07-14 11:00:00 | 49237.21 |
| 2021-07-14 11:10:00 | 111742.17 |
| .... | ... |
| .... | ... |
| .... | ... |
| 2021-07-25 08:00:00 | -29903.92 |
| 2021-07-25 08:10:00 | -19403.22 |
| 2021-07-25 08:20:00 | 2361.4 |

Comment: Are you familiar with this module? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [perform integration on columns of Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58608688/perform-integration-on-columns-of-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Sort the columns by time, convert the times to integers or floats in the unit you want (seconds or days or hours or whatever), then `sum((time[i+1]-time[i]) * (moment[i+1]+moment[i])/2  for i in range(0, nb_columns-1))` and the result will be in the corresponding unit.